# Laravel 5.1 Is it possible to loop the view in my controller?

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5.1

I am using laravel/dom-pdf to generate invoices. the problem is that I have 500 accounts to generate,I manage to pass the data to my views and loop it.but I am having problem in saving the pdf. because the saving pdf code is in my controller..

TestpdfController

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('invoices.viewinvoicepdf');
$pdf->save(path/to/save'/'.$inv->accountid.'.pdf'); // problem here is that i cannot grab the accountid for each user and only the last account will be created.
```

my second option is put inside to foreach, but I think it is not efficient because it renders the views 500 times because of the foreach.

```
foreach($invoices as $inv){
  $pdf = PDF::loadView('invoices.viewinvoicepdf',compact('invoices'));
    $pdf->save(path/to/save'/'.$inv->accountid.'.pdf');
}
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you'll need to save each PDF file separately, I don't think you a any choice than to use a loop. I assume you have a loop in your view file. You can move that loop in the controller instead and have your view file accept only one `invoice`.